# How to add the French language package and use it in Tinymce package?

Tags: .net, dll, tinymce

We are using Moxiecode.tinyMCE.dll in one of our project. This project is a ASP.net website using C#. We added one text area. All the controls are working as expected in English. Please let me know the steps to add another text area in the same page which must be able to take the French characters as input? How to change the language of the ribbon items to French using for this new text area?. I am having normal English keyboard. Can I make some programmatic changes so that I can type the French characters using my current keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the tinymce init/configuration for that second editor.
There is a parameter called [language](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3alanguage). Make sure you got the correct language pack. You can get it here: http://www.tinymce.com/i18n/index.php?ctrl=lang&act=download&pr_id=1

If it is propperly installed set in your tinymce configuration

```
language: 'fr',
```

Keyboard settings can be changed via your system settings.
You can even edit the language files to your needs.
Language files are stored under

`tiny_mce/plugins/'plugin_name'/lang/'language_code'.js`

Comment: This approach is working in the sample project. But it is not working in the current application.

Comment: please post your full tinymce initialization here